# Basic List operation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried a very basic code in the python interactive shell

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> id(a)
36194248L
>>> a.append(4)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> id(a)
36194248L
>>>
>>> id([1,2,3])
36193288L
>>> id([1,2,3].append(4))
506033800L
>>> id([1,2,3].append(5))
506033800L
>>> id([1,2,3].append(6))
506033800L
```

Q: When i assign a list to a variable named 'a', and try to append more value, the id() does not change but if i try the same thing without assigning to a variable,the id() changes.Since lists are mutable(i.e. allow change at same memory address),why this behaviour is seen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list.append()` returns `None`, not the list.

You are getting the `id()` result for that object, and `None` is a singleton. It'll *always* be the same for a given Python interpreter run:

```
>>> id(None)
4514447768
>>> [].append(1) is None
True
>>> id([].append(1))
4514447768
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `list.append` returns `None`, you are calling `id(None)`, which there will only be one instance of.